# ¿Cómo promediar la columna de una fila en un arreglo bidimensional en C?

Tags: array, c

Verán tengo un par de inconvenientes, necesito crear un programa para simular unas mesas de votaciones, tengo que crear un arreglo bidimensional donde las filas serán las mesas de votaciones en este caso son 4 mesas y las columnas serán los candidatos que serán 5, creé el arreglo donde se pueden ingresar datos para ir llenando el arreglo, al momento de leer el total de voto de los candidatos en las diferentes mesas todo bien con el primer candidato,

Tengo los siguientes incovenientes:

- Para el segundo candidato el valor de la primera mesa se multiplica x2, no se reinicia el contador.
- Para poder sacarle el promedio, no me da.

Adjunto lo que llevo de programa, cualquier consulta será muy bienvenida.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int votos[4][5],mesa,candidatos,h[10];
    float suma=0.0,Tvotos=0.0,prom;
    int z,x;
    
    for(mesa=0;mesa<4;mesa++)
    {
        for (candidatos=0;candidatos<=4;candidatos++)
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de votos para el candidato [%d] en la mesa #%d: ",mesa+1,candidatos+1);
            do
            {
                scanf("%d",&votos[mesa][candidatos]);
            } while(!(votos[mesa][candidatos]>=1) && (votos[mesa][candidatos]<=100));
            
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    for (mesa=0;mesa<4;mesa++)
    {
        printf("\t\t Matriz de la Mesa de elecciones %d\n\n",mesa+1);
        for (candidatos=0;candidatos<=4;candidatos++)
        {
            printf("En la mesa [%d], el candidato [%d] tiene ==> %d votos\n",mesa+1,candidatos+1,votos[mesa][candidatos]);
            suma=suma+votos[mesa][candidatos];
            Tvotos+=votos[mesa][candidatos];
        }
        h[candidatos]=suma;
        printf("Suma de los votos es: %.2f\n",suma);
        prom=ceil(h[candidatos]*100/Tvotos);
        printf("Con un promedio de votos de: %.2f%\n\n",prom);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código está plagado de malas prácticas que conllevan los errores que estás sufriendo. Voy a enumerarlas:

1. **Variables sin usar**: Cuanto más código escribas, más código necesitas revisar y más esfuerzo hay que hacer para entenderlo, procura no añadir al código líneas que no sean necesarias (las variables `z` y `x` sobran).
2. **Cabeceras sin usar**: Igual que el punto anterior, pero con cabeceras (las cabeceras `<conio.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` sobran).
3. **Variables demasiado amplias**: Es más fácil razonar sobre las variables cuando éstas tienen un ámbito pequeño, cuanto más amplio sea el ámbito de una variable mas interacciones potenciales tienen en todo el ámbito y más código hay que revisar para comprender su cometido (reduce el ámbito de tus variables, por ejemplo declarando los índices de los `for` en el propio bucle).
4. **Bucles inconsistentes**: En el primer bucle pones un límite `mesa<4` y en el segundo un límite `candidatos<=4`, estás utilizando dos criterios diferentes para una misma tarea, esto es confuso y propenso a errores.
5. **Usa constantes**: Los [números mágicos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) hacen que tu programa sea más difícil de mantener y entender, pon nombre a tus constantes.
6. **Nombres auto-explicativos**: El cometido de una variable debe ser fácilmente comprensible al leer su nombre, nombres como `h`, `Tvotos`, `prom`, `z` y `x` no explican nada. Por otro lado, cuando escojas los nombres se consistente en su cardinalidad, es confuso que el índice de mesas esté en singular (`mesa`) mientras que el de candidatos en plural (`candidatos`).
7. **Deja respirar a tu código**: Comprimir el texto del código hace que su lectura sea más pesada y puede hacer que los errores se pasen por alto con más frecuencia. Antaño cuando las pantallas sólo permitían 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto comprimir el texto tenía sentido, hoy día es absurdo.

Siguiendo esas buenas prácticas, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
// Solo las cabeceras necesarias.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Constantes numéricas.
#define MESAS 4
#define CANDIDATOS 5

int main(void)
{
    // Las constantes numericas ayudan a entender el conjunto de datos.
    // No son necesarias mas variables en este contexto: el codigo esta mas claro.
    int votos[MESAS][CANDIDATOS];
    float total_votos = 0;

    // Las constantes numericas ayudan a entender los bucles
    // Los indices de los bucle solo viven en este contexto.
    for (int mesa = 0; mesa != MESAS; ++mesa)
    {
        for (int candidato = 0; candidato != CANDIDATOS; ++candidato)
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de votos para el candidato [%d] en la mesa #%d: ", mesa + 1, candidato + 1);
            do
            {
                scanf("%d",&votos[mesa][candidato]);
            } while (!(votos[mesa][candidato] >= 1) && (votos[mesa][candidato] <= 100));

            total_votos += votos[mesa][candidato];
        }
    }

    for (int mesa = 0; mesa != MESAS; ++mesa)
    {
        // Esta variable se reinicia en cada vuelta del bucle.
        int suma = 0;

        printf("\t\t Matriz de la Mesa de elecciones %d\n\n", mesa + 1);
        for (int candidato = 0; candidato != CANDIDATOS; ++candidato)
        {
            printf("En la mesa [%d], el candidato [%d] tiene ==> %d votos\n", mesa + 1, candidato + 1, votos[mesa][candidato]);
            suma +=  votos[mesa][candidato];
        }

        printf("Suma de los votos es: %.2f\n", suma);
        printf("Con un promedio de votos de: %.2f%\n\n", 100 * suma / total_votos);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Siguiendo las buenas prácticas, verás que la variable `suma`, al estar en el ámbito que le corresponde (punto 3 de los consejos) se restablece a 0 y da la suma correcta. Al haber eliminado variables innecesarias (punto 1 de los consejos) el algoritmo está más claro.